# How to store product quantities in an array

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have a data array that totals all the items in the cart for all the products as one number.

I've been trying to figure out a way to get a data array count() all the different totals of all the different items in the cart and have them presented in my data layer comma separated. I hope that makes sense.

```
if ($order->getId()) {
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    $itemIds = array();
    $itemNames = array();
    $itemPrices = array();
    $itemMargins = array();
    $itemTypes = array();
    $itemGenders = array();
    $itemSports = array();
    $itemCategoryIds = array();
    $itemCategoryNames = array();
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item */
    foreach ($items as $item) {

        // Get the parent item - it is NOT included in the quote due to
        // customizations made by the OrganicInternet module for simple
        // product pricing. So I had to come up with another way to get it.
        $options = $item->getProductOptions();
        $parent = $item->getProduct();
        if (array_key_exists('info_buyRequest', $options)) {
            if (array_key_exists('cpid', $options['info_buyRequest'])) {
                $parentId = $options['info_buyRequest']['cpid'];
                $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('season')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('gender')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('sport')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $parentId)
                    ->getFirstItem();
            }
        }

        $itemIds[] = $item->getSku();
        $itemNames[] = $parent->getName();
        $itemPrices[] = $item->getBasePrice() ?: 0;
        $itemMargins[] = $this->_calculateMargin($parent, null, $item);
        $itemTypes[] = $parent->getAttributeText('season');
        $itemGenders[] = $parent->getAttributeText('gender');
        $itemSports[] = $parent->getAttributeText('sport') ?: 'Other';
        $categories = $this->_getAllCategoryIdsAndNames($item->getProduct());
        $itemCategoryIds[] = $categories['id'];
        $itemCategoryNames[] = $categories['name'];
    }

    // # Products

    $data['u1'] = count($items);
```

The above will return:

> dataLayer = [{"visitorLoginState":"Logged out","visitorType":"NOT LOGGED IN","visitorLifetimeValue":0,"visitorExistingCustomer":"No","u1":2,"u2":["889623392590","889623135517"]

It shows a total of 2 products for the U1 variable and the two sku's for the u2 variable in the data array.

If i have multiple products for the first sku i want it to seperate the quantities. ie..  `"u1":1,1,3`

Would i use `array_sum`or some type of multi-dimensional array to acquire my needs?

Comment: Is it necessary to store all this data in one gigantic multi-nested array?  This is difficult to follow, at best.  You might have an easier time if you broke this down to a more atomic level.

Comment: @Matt1776, I'm open for suggestions or any other means of getting the data.

Comment: I'm suggesting a bit of a refactor, I do not know your problem or your data well enough to making such a suggestion, other than that you might want to consider using more than one array, or a hash/map/dictionary object, or simply nesting less data.  It becomes very difficult to track the data when it's nested inside one object.  Re-think how you want to store and retrieve the data, and the solution will become more clear to you.

Comment: Can you describe anywhere in your code that : how I am supposed to know if there are multiple products for some sku? What variable or functions tells about no of products of different category in one sku? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 6):

> If i have multiple products for the first sku i want it to seperate
>   the quantities. ie.. "u1":1,1,3

It is not exactly clear to me is the relationship between sku and product and which variables in your array refer to which. I make the following presumptions:
1) A `product` is equivalent to one `$items` element
2) A `sku` is a unique `$itemIds[]` value

I use the array key as a simple way to keep track for each unique sku and the value to keep track of the product count for the sku.

```
if ($order->getId()) {
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    $itemIds = array();
    $itemNames = array();
    $itemPrices = array();
    $itemMargins = array();
    $itemTypes = array();
    $itemGenders = array();
    $itemSports = array();
    $itemCategoryIds = array();
    $itemCategoryNames = array();

    // My addition (UPDATE: fixed to the correct variable name)
    $uniqueItemIds = array();

    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item */
    foreach ($items as $item) {

        // Get the parent item - it is NOT included in the quote due to
        // customizations made by the OrganicInternet module for simple
        // product pricing. So I had to come up with another way to get it.
        $options = $item->getProductOptions();
        $parent = $item->getProduct();
        if (array_key_exists('info_buyRequest', $options)) {
            if (array_key_exists('cpid', $options['info_buyRequest'])) {
                $parentId = $options['info_buyRequest']['cpid'];
                $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('season')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('gender')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('sport')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $parentId)
                    ->getFirstItem();
            }
        }
        // *******************************
        // My addition / changes
        $sku = $item->getSku();
        $itemIds[] = $sku;        // I don't use this but keep $itemIds for compatibility            

        // use the array key to track counts for each sku
        if (!isset($uniqueItemIds[$sku])){
            $uniqueItemIds[$sku] = 1;   // UPDATE: fixed to start at 1 not 0
        } else {
            $uniqueItemIds[$sku]++;
        }
        // *******************************
        $itemNames[] = $parent->getName();
        $itemPrices[] = $item->getBasePrice() ?: 0;
        $itemMargins[] = $this->_calculateMargin($parent, null, $item);
        $itemTypes[] = $parent->getAttributeText('season');
        $itemGenders[] = $parent->getAttributeText('gender');
        $itemSports[] = $parent->getAttributeText('sport') ?: 'Other';
        $categories = $this->_getAllCategoryIdsAndNames($item->getProduct());
        $itemCategoryIds[] = $categories['id'];
        $itemCategoryNames[] = $categories['name'];
    }

    // show # Products
    // "u1":1,1,3 NOTE: this should be a string => "u1":"1,1,3"
    $data['u1'] = "";
    foreach ($uniqueItemIds as $key => $val)
        // show unique skus in u2
        $data['u2'][] = $key;
        // show counts for each sku in u1
        if (strlen($data['u1'] == 0)){
            $data['u1'] = (string)$value;
        } else {
           $data['u1'] .= ("," . $value);
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like...

```
if ($order->getId()) {
    .....
    .....
    .....
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item */
    $sku_based_array = array();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        ......
        ......
        ......
        $categories = $this->_getAllCategoryIdsAndNames($item->getProduct());
        $itemCategoryIds[] = $categories['id'];
        $itemCategoryNames[] = $categories['name'];

        if (isset($sku_based_array[$item->getSku()])) {
            $sku_based_array[$item->getSku()] = $sku_based_array[$item->getSku()]++;
        } else {
            $sku_based_array[$item->getSku()] = 1;
        }
    }

    // # Products

    $data['u1'] = array_values($sku_based_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue with your data here is that everything in an `$item` is hidden behind an accessor. Rather than creating multitudes of arrays, I would suggest either creating a new object to house the information, or just modifying the `$item` directly.

Messing with the object directly has the risk of you accidentally using a variable name that exists in a `protected` or `private` scope though, so probably best to use your own, like so.

```
if ($order->getId()) {
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

    // only need one array, no need for all data points to have their own
    $myItems = [];

    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item */
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // basic shell
        $myItem = [];

        // get $options and $parent
        // ...

        // build your own data object
        $myItem['sku'] = $item->getSku();
        $myItem['name'] = $parent->getName();
        $myItem['price'] = $item->getBasePrice() ?: 0;
        $myItem['margin'] = $this->_calculateMargin($parent, null, $item);
        $myItem['type'] = $parent->getAttributeText('season');
        $myItem['gender'] = $parent->getAttributeText('gender');
        $myItem['sport'] = $parent->getAttributeText('sport') ?: 'Other';
        $categories = $this->_getAllCategoryIdsAndNames($item->getProduct());
        $myItem['categoryId'] = $categories['id'];
        $myItem['categoryName'] = $categories['name'];

        $myItems[] = $myItem;
    }

    // At this point, $myItems is manipulable by all the array_* functions

    // number of items e.g. 3
    $data['u1'] = count($myItems);
    // array of skus e.g. ["889623392590","889623392590","889623135517"]
    // note: can use objects for $myItem if on PHP 7 
    //       if you like -> notation better (in the loop)
    $skus = array_column($myItems, 'sku');
    // array of skus with counts e.g. ["889623392590" => 2, "889623135517" => 1]
    $skus_with_counts = array_count_values($skus);
    // just the counts (assuming indexes on other arrays must match) e.g. [2, 1]
    // note: might be useful if you want to keep the counts as an array in dataLayer
    $sku_counts = array_values($skus_with_counts);
    // if you want this as a comma-separated list for u1, e.g. "2,1"
    // note: will also work if you implode $skus_with_counts
    $data['u1'] = implode(',', $sku_counts);
    // get a list of unique SKUs (both will work), e.g. ["889623392590","889623135517"]
    $data['u2'] = array_unique($skus);
    $data['u2'] = array_keys($skus_with_counts);
}
```

Most of these kinds of PHP functions will work on your other data types as well if you want to do counting and clustering, and as you point out, you can run sum operations over them as well if you wish.

PHP array manipulation references: [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column), [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array_count_values), [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values), [`implode`](http://php.net/implode), [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique), [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys).

As a sidebar, `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` does have a [`getParentItemId()`](http://doc4dev.net/doc/Magento/1/class-Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item.html) method available and a [`getQtyOptions`](http://doc4dev.net/doc/Magento/1/source-class-Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item.html#_getQtyOptions) method, which returns both the quantity and the product model.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code it looks like it will only every return one product as the `$parent` variable is overwritten to get a first item. I have added a new variable named `$itemProductCounts` this will be returned to the output `$data` array as `itemProductCounts` I suspect this will always equal one.

```
<?php
if ($order->getId()) {
    $items              = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    $itemIds            = array();
    $itemNames          = array();
    $itemPrices         = array();
    $itemMargins        = array();
    $itemTypes          = array();
    $itemGenders        = array();
    $itemSports         = array();
    $itemCategoryIds    = array();
    $itemCategoryNames  = array();
    $itemProductCounts  = array();
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item */
    foreach ($items as $item) {

        // Get the parent item - it is NOT included in the quote due to
        // customizations made by the OrganicInternet module for simple
        // product pricing. So I had to come up with another way to get it.
        $options    = $item->getProductOptions();
        $parent     = $item->getProduct();
        if (array_key_exists('info_buyRequest', $options)) {
            if (array_key_exists('cpid', $options['info_buyRequest'])) {
                $parentId = $options['info_buyRequest']['cpid'];
                $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('season')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('gender')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('sport')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $parentId)
                    ->getFirstItem();
            }
        }

        $itemIds[]                          = $item->getSku();
        $itemNames[]                        = $parent->getName();
        $itemPrices[]                       = $item->getBasePrice() ?: 0;
        $itemMargins[]                      = $this->_calculateMargin($parent, null, $item);
        $itemTypes[]                        = $parent->getAttributeText('season');
        $itemGenders[]                      = $parent->getAttributeText('gender');
        $itemSports[]                       = $parent->getAttributeText('sport') ?: 'Other';
        $categories                         = $this->_getAllCategoryIdsAndNames($item->getProduct());
        $itemCategoryIds[]                  = $categories['id'];
        $itemCategoryNames[]                = $categories['name'];
        $itemProductCounts[$item->getSku()] = count($parent);
    }

    // # Products

    $data['u1'] = count($items);
    $data['itemProductCounts'] = $itemProductCounts;
```

With that all being said, the code above should get you close to what you need, you should replace the line `$itemProductCounts[$item->getSku()] = count($parent);` with the correct array with the product counts for that SKU.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are mixing things.

In a simple sistem you should have:

- Order has an array of OrderedItems
- Each OrderedItem stores ProductObject and OrderedQuantity
- And the ProductObject contains all product data.

So in your example instead of counting SKUs you must have $item->quantity field and you should work with that when you add/delete/edit order contents.

Comment: The OP is working with an existing system (Magento) and cannot control the design. He's also talking about products that are variations of each other, but have the same SKU, so the quantity approach you mention does not apply. Also nothing in this response actually helps answer the OP.

Comment: I slightly disagree with you.

Comment: OP actually fills all the data in the provided code from the parent object which is the product model. + even with your remark the introducing of quantity would make calculation easier. 

And storing copies of anything is always a bad idea. And that is what OP actually does

Comment: OP is working from a QuoteItem model, which can provide quantities (I modified my answer to _provide a specific reference_) and the product model, although depending on the system implementation, he may not be able to use that to differentiate in the way desired for the JSON dataLayer object. The question was also not 'how do I design a system for this' it was 'how do I get the information I want using PHP with this data'. Using copies is also not necessarily bad depending on what you're doing, sometimes it's important to use a copy; blanket generalizations without justification are pointless.